# Correct permissions to upload to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have two buckets, and someone else set up the permission for them.  One allows uploads, and the second one isn't.  I checked the permissions on both, and neither have a bucket policy or CORS Configuration that I can see.  These are the permissions for the one that is allowing uploads
[image]

I've opened up the permissions even more for the other bucket, but it still doesn't allow uploads.
[image]

Besides those places is there somewhere else that you would set permissions that I'm missing?  The Amazon docs just talk about this and bucket policy, but as I said, the Bucket Policy and CORS configuration for the one that is working is blank.  I'm not sure what I need to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the issue was, but the original app was written to use the East Coast data center.  When I changed to bucket to that location suddenly it started working again.  My only assumption is that someone must have hard coded it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything under [Identity & Access Management (IAM)](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#home)? There might be policy preventing you from access bucket

Here is a link explain how IAM policy work:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3

Comment: There is one user created there and the only policy attached is full access.  That's not even used for the app I'm working on, it's for a streaming app on a server.